# Akka remoting creating remote actor by name

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, akka, actor, playframework-2.2

Is it possible to create remote actor having only it's name (class name), not the class itself?

I have a client (ClientActor) -> server (ServerActor) communication and both actors are strictly related to implementation of his environment, and I have to create ServerActor from client, when I'm using:

```
 Akka.system.actorOf(Props[ServerActor].withDeploy(Deploy(scope = RemoteScope(address))))
```

I have to pass class itself, but I don't want to add server dependency to client.

Comment: You can always load the class with Class.forName(serverActorClassName), but of course it must be available on your client's classpath.

Comment: You can create a FactoryActor on the Server to which you can pass a desired actor type name string (like "ServerActor") and receive an ActorRef of a ServerActor implementation back. Your FactoryActor may create ServerActor implementation with static (different on different server types) or dynamic (Class.forName) linking to the desired implementation class.